# CakePHP 3 dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, cakephp, addition

I´ve build an APP where I want to add content in a table dynamically and that on one Page. So I am adding input fields with jQuery to the page (1, 5 or 10) and store this in my database.

First I wonder if this is best practise. Seconde why I get the error

`Notice (8): Undefined variable: content [APP/Template/Contents/add.ctp, line 8]`

My ContentConroller Add Function

```
public function add()
{
    $content = $this->Contents->newEntity();
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $contents = $this->Contents->newEntities($this->request->data());
        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $content->article_id = $id;
            $this->Contents->save($content);
        }
            $this->Flash->success(__('Added'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller'=> 'articles', 'action' => 'index']);
        }




    $this->set(compact('content'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
}
```

My Contents add.ctp (without dynamically loading inputs so far)

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Contents'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contents form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($content) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Content') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('0.article_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('1.article_id');
            echo $this->Form->input('0.type');
            echo $this->Form->input('0.position');
        echo $this->Form->input('1.type');
        echo $this->Form->input('1.position');
            echo $this->Form->input('0.text');
            echo $this->Form->input('1.text');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

</div>
```

EDIT: Fixed it. But still. Best Practice?

Comment: you only have definded `$contents` variable and not `$content`

Comment: Okay, if i use $content tho it throws an error "Unable to find table class for current entity"